# Is there a way to extract and output a portion of a string in a text file?

Tags: python, xml, string, text

I want to extract from a text file a string that is enclosed in the "" (Description>)""(<Description) and the output of each string in a new line, preferebly written in Python.

I want a hint as to how to achieve something like it so I can replicate it and I do not want the entire code.

Comment: Please show us some example input and output and what you have tried so far!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I honestly don't have a clue on how to start doing it beside first reading the file and selecting each line my issue is what do I need to put to "filter" after selecting each line of string that it reads

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing or tutorial service. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't write it for you. Please [edit] your question and add your code. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask]. That said: Look into [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: Okay, I will rewrite what I written before and edit my question.